# Video Streaming in iphone does not work

Tags: iphone, ios, video, video-streaming, mpmovieplayercontroller

I'm developing an application that stream videos. I use this code to stream video:

```
NSURL *fileURL=[[NSURL alloc]initWithString:self.content.trialURL];
moviePlayerController = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL:fileURL];
[moviePlayerController.view setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 70, 320, 270)];
[self.view addSubview:moviePlayerController.view];
moviePlayerController.fullscreen = YES;
[moviePlayerController play];

[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                         selector:@selector(movieExitFullScreen:)
                                             name:MPMoviePlayerWillExitFullscreenNotification
                                           object:moviePlayerController];
_isMPlayerMode = YES;
```

The url is http://server5.sefr-yek.com:8081/lifetest/downloadMedia.do?method=content&url=772/trial/test.mp4_conv.mp4

The backend has action that has access to files that buffers the file and send to iphone.
But iPhone could not play it, and stay in loading state. 
The android device has not problem to play video but the iPhone could not play.

What's wrong in my code?

Comment: What encoding does the video have?

Comment: @wain The encoding codec is H264

Comment: The video you link isn't valid to play in safari. How is it sent? Mime type? Additional data?

Comment: The iPhone or iPad safari does not play this video, but the safari in mac plays it without problem. Mime Type: video/MP4, pixel Type: BGR24 channel:2, bit rate: 44100

Comment: The video converted by using Xuggler Convertor

Comment: The url you provided is giving this error `ediaPlayerErrorDomain Code=-11850` which means "The HTTP server sending the media resource is not configured as expected. This might mean that the
server does not support byte range requests".